# Safe to compare DB data as Java String in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm pulling row data from two Oracle DB's into two String List. I want to compare these rows by iterating through these lists and running a basic .equals() comparison. Is it safe/practical to iterate through each list and compare each element via String comparison?

Example:

```
List<String> resultSet1 = <result set of rows from DB1 as string list>
List<String> resultSet2 = <result set of rows from DB2 as string list>
```

//ASSUMING result sets are same size and point to rows with same primary/composite key

```
for(int i = 0; i < resultSet1.size(); i++)
{
  if(resultSet1.get(i).equals(resultSet2.get(i))){
   <DO SOMETHING>
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your assumption states, your result sets need to be the same size. Further, they must both be sorted in the same order and include the same set of keys.  That is, if recordSet1 has {1,2,3,4}, then recordSet2 must have {1,2,3,4}.  {1,2,4,3} won't cut it, nor will {1,2,3,5}.

Among other things, that means that your List must use an actual implementation class that preserves order (or allows you to control the order).

Personally, I would approach this by joining the data *in the database*.  If that's not possible (e.g., there are two separate databases and you don't have good distributed query features in them), then I'd probably use HashMaps instead of Lists -- with the key of the hashmap being the key of the data.  That way, you iterate through the keySet of resultSet1 and look up the corresponding value from resultSet2 using that key.  It'd be clearer and less error prone.